# Laravel Vue Js Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pagination, vue-component

Hello there this isnt a programming question i am just gathering an opinion i am currently using a most commonly used laravel pagination library https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination everything is working good except for one thing which is that when i reload the page it takes me back to page number one is there anyway by which i can force the application to have the same current_page value if the reload happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

You can keep the `current_page` on the local storage, send it to the `perm` when loading.